# Choosing which params to send in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a checkout form that allows a user to specify a billing address and a shipping address. The behavior I require is that

1) if a billing address is supplied but no shipping address then the shipping address is the billing address

2) If a shipping address is supplied then the shipping address should passed as the shipping address

```
shipping: {
  first_name: params[:first_name] unless params[:shipping_first_name] != nil,
  last_name: params[:last_name] unless params[:shipping_last_name] != nil
}
```

This obviously does not work and am unsure on how to set this up

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should do it:

```
shipping: {
    first_name: params[:shipping_first_name].presence || params[:first_name].presence,
    last_name: params[:shipping_last_name].presence || params[:last_name].presence
}
```

[`Object#presence`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence) method will return the value `nil` if value is not [`present?`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark).  The first of the two values in the `||` expression that is not `nil`/`blank` will be the value of the expression.

Comment: so this checks if `params[:shipping_first_name]` exists, if not fallback to `params[:first_name]`, thanks..simple really :-), silly me

Comment: Yeah, I updated the expression - I think you need it to fallback to `params[:first_name]`.